# Doctrine subtract on-the-fly two columns as a third

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

### Expressed in MySQL, what I wish:

```
SELECT article.sellprice - article.cost AS margin
FROM article
```

### My attempt in DQL (note that `margin` does not exist in my entity):

```
SELECT a, a.sellprice - a.cost AS a.margin
FROM ArticleBundle:Article a"
```

Results in an exception `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 47: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'`. Attempt to get it outside of the entity:

```
SELECT a, a.sellprice - a.cost AS margin
FROM ArticleBundle:Article a"
```

And some variations of that code; that messes up with my result, causing a twig error `Key "nom" for array with keys "0, margin" does not exist.`. In fact, `a.nom` exists; when reverting to:

```
SELECT a
FROM ArticleBundle:Article a
```

No error at all. Any clues to get my calculated on-the-fly result?

Comment: The second attempt should give you a [*mixed result*](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results). You would only need to update the view layer (twig in your case). Aside, if you only need the `margin` for selection purposes, you can try [`a, a.sellprice - a.cost AS HIDDEN margin`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that value must bubble up to the twig, according to the comment of [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi) (many thanks by the way), I ended up with the second try:

```
SELECT a, a.sellprice - a.cost AS margin
FROM ArticleBundle:Article a"
```

Tuning the twig to parse that mixed content:

```
{% for mixed_content in pagination %}
    <tr>
    {% set article = mixed_content|first %}
    {% set margin = mixed_content.margin %}
        <td>{{ article.nom }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.margin}}</td>
```

Hoping that may help anyone.

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to accept your answer. I think it's a good solution for the given problem.

Comment: Indeed, but there are 2 days before I can accept my own answer.
If you write your own, I could validate it a.s.a.p. ;-)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that ;) In 2 days then. I think, your's is fine, it has all it needs to.